# How can I prove there exists countable sub-collection the sigma-algebra generated by which contains an element?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

I don't think I can make proper subject for this question. So I'll just write the whole problem verbatim below. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of sets and $E$ and element in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. Then there is a countable subcollection $\mathcal{C}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ such that $E$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_0$ generated by $\mathcal{C}_0$. [Hint: Let $\mathcal{A}'$ be the union of all $\sigma$-algebras generated by countable subsets of $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathcal{A}'\supseteq \mathcal{A}$.]

As someone may notice, this is the problem appearing in H.L. Royden, Real Analysis, 3rd edition.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: it is sufficient to prove that $\mathcal{A}'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @NateEldredge Could you guide me as to why? Why it that sufficient?

Comment: Because $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra **generated** by $\mathcal{C}$.  This means, by definition, that every other $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$ must also contain $\mathcal{A}$.  Now I think it's your turn to share your progress.